# Error reporting in Django for 403 errors

Tags: django, error-reporting

Currently I have my production environment set up so that MANAGERS are emailed any time there's a 500 error. I would also like to be emailed anytime someone tries to access something they don't have permission to (i.e., they produce a 403 error).

As far as I can see, you can easily get Django to email you when someone produces a 404 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#errors), but there's nothing like this for a 403.

What's the best way to get Django to send emails when someone produces a 403?

Comment: Not sure if this will work but its worth a try https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view

Comment: Don't think that'll do it Dillon. That option controls what the user sees when they produce a 403. I could always override it and manually send an email I suppose. I was hoping there was a built in approach to this though.

Comment: you can write your own decorator to do that. but that would be to specific views.

Comment: I'm certain there's a much DRYer way of doing it.

Comment: http://theglenbot.com/creating-a-custom-http403-exception-in-django/

Comment: I'd recommend to use sentry + raven and add a middleware snippet to log 403 events.